# Need to get a particular value from XML

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq

I have followed many tutorials here on LINQ to XML http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564

The terminology for the XML documents is confusing.
Could someone please help me to write the code snippet that would extract the "Name" value from this xml based on a condition for example.

I need colSDate and colAcqDate because Visible is True but not colSeqNo because it does not have the Visible property or it is set to False.

```
<XtraSerializer version="1.0" application="View">
  <property name="#LayoutVersion" />
  <property name="ActiveFilterEnabled">true</property>
  <property name="Columns" iskey="true" value="286">
    <property name="Item1" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Name">colSeqNo</property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item2" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Visible">true</property>
      <property name="VisibleIndex">0</property>
      <property name="Name">colSDate</property>
    </property>
    <property name="Item3" isnull="true" iskey="true">
      <property name="Visible">true</property>
      <property name="VisibleIndex">1</property>
      <property name="Name">colAcqDate</property>
    </property>
  </property>
  <property name="ActiveFilterString" />
  <property name="GroupSummarySortInfoState" />
  <property name="FindFilterText" />
  <property name="FindPanelVisible">false</property>
</XtraSerializer>
```

I am trying to write some reasonably performing data access code but the absurd requirements are making it difficult. Any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using LINQ to XML:

```
Dim result = From d In xml.Descendants("property")
             Where d.Attribute("name").Value = "Visible" AndAlso
                   d.Value = "true"
             From e As XElement In d.Parent.Elements
             Where e.Attribute("name").Value = "Name"
             Select e.Value
```

Comment: The result of the Descendants method includes the root element which has no "name" attribute. The query will throw an exception when trying to get the value of the "name" attribute. Use `From d In xml.Descendants("property")` instead.

Comment: @pescolino: Fixed (although it did work for me in VS for some reason).

Comment: @pescolino: Descendants does not include self, see reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635(v=vs.110).aspx `Note that this method will not return itself in the resulting IEnumerable(Of T). See DescendantsAndSelf if you need to include the current XElement in the results.`

Comment: If you call it on the XDocument the root element is included (at least for me). If it is called on an XElement (e.g. doc.Root) the element itself is not included.

Comment: @pescolino: Oh okay, that makes sense now. So another way of doing it is using `xml.Root`. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

or using `XPath` (not sure if you want vb or c# code, not a huge dif):

```vb
Dim x As XmlNodeList = ' ... pardon the break here, want to get it all in window.
d.SelectNodes(".//property[@name='Visible'][.='true']/../property[@name='Name']")
```